# If $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-t^a}{\ln t} dt=\ln\frac56$, then what is the product of the values ​that $a$ can take?

Tags: analysis

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-t^a}{\ln t}
dt=\ln\frac56$, then what is the product of the values ​​that $a$ can take?
I tried to substitute $u=\ln t$, then the integral became $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^u-e^{u(a+1)}}{u}du.$ I checked the gamma function but I couldn't find a way to solve.

Comment: The integral never converges (except for $a=0$).

Comment: If you consider $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{1-t^a}{\ln(t)}dt$ though, the only value is $a=\dfrac{1}{5}$.